# If $a_n \geq b_n$, $b_n \leq |c_n|$ with $c_n \to 0$, does this imply $\liminf a_n \geq 0?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_n \geq b_n$ where $b_n \leq |c_n|$ with $c_n \to 0$.

Does this imply that
$$\liminf a_n \geq 0?$$

These are all real-valued sequences. I don't think it is enough to conclude.

Comment: No: $a_n=b_n=-n$ and $c_n=1/n$

Comment: Perhaps you mean $|b_n| \le c_n$.

Comment: @GEdgar Does that change the answer?

Comment: I think if so then the answer is yes, just by using relationship of liminf and limsup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. Take the constant sequences $a_n = b_n = -1$ and $c_n = 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

No. As a simple counterexample, you can take $a_n = -1$, $b_n = -2$ and $c_n = 0$, all constant sequences.